# a right-associative triple colon operator

Tags: scala

Although a triple colon is a right-associative operator, the following result says it's not true, is it?

```
List(3, 4, 5) ::: List(18, 19, 20) //> List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 20)
```

From my point of view, the result should be `List(18, 19, 20, 3, 4, 5)` since it's the same as saying:

```
List(18, 19, 20).:::(List(3, 4, 5))
```

Do I understand the definition of being a right-associative wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

```
def :::(prefix: List[A]): List[A]
[use case] Adds the elements of a given list in front of this list.
```

Example:

```
List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) = List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2)) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
prefix  - The list elements to prepend.
returns - a list resulting from the concatenation of the given list prefix and this list.
```

This says it all. As for the right-associative operations, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity is irrelevant in the expression

```
x ::: y
```

The associativity of `:::` determines whether

```
x ::: y ::: z
```

is interpreted as (if left-associative)

```
( x ::: y ) ::: z
```

or as (if right-associative)

```
x ::: ( y ::: z )
```

Since in Scala all operators ending in a colon are right-associative, the latter interpretation is used: assuming x,y,z are variables of type List, first y is prepended to z, and then x is prepended to that.

Comment: therefore, `x ::: ( y ::: z )` ==> `List(z, y, x)`?

Comment: No, sorry -- I was just using x, y, and z to represent Lists.  I'll update the answer.